# Can't run iPhoneSimulator

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

Using the latest Gluon build (4.0.1) on Mac (10.12.1) with XCode (8.1). When I run the the launchIPhoneSimulator task I get the following exception. Any ideas what the issue might be.

Also noticed that I have no org/robovm/robovm-dist/ROBOVM_VERSION/unpacked/robovm-ROBOVM_VERSION/bin directory locally as mentioned in the documentation.

Thanks

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launchIPhoneSimulator'.
> org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Command '/var/folders/1k/0wptgkp92nx0m02tncktfmcw0000gn/T/ios-sim4189806266868947871 showdevicetypes' failed with output: 2016-10-30 09:09:16.601 ios-sim4189806266868947871[31818:4531950] +[SimDeviceSet defaultSet]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x104d49118
  2016-10-30 09:09:16.601 ios-sim4189806266868947871[31818:4531950] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[SimDeviceSet defaultSet]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x104d49118'
  *** First throw call stack:
  (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd536048b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffe9ac2cad objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd53e1bd4 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd52d2b55 ___forwarding___ + 1061
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd52d26a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   ios-sim4189806266868947871          0x00000001016c3c21 -[iPhoneSimulator showDeviceTypes] + 75
    6   ios-sim4189806266868947871          0x00000001016c5dd1 -[iPhoneSimulator runWithArgc:argv:] + 3111
    7   ios-sim4189806266868947871          0x00000001016c5fb9 main + 101
    8   ios-sim4189806266868947871          0x00000001016c3150 start + 52
    9   ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
  )
  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (Exit value: 134)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.222 secs
Command '/var/folders/1k/0wptgkp92nx0m02tncktfmcw0000gn/T/ios-sim4189806266868947871 showdevicetypes' failed with output: 2016-10-30 09:09:16.601 ios-sim4189806266868947871[31818:4531950] +[SimDeviceSet defaultSet]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x104d49118
2016-10-30 09:09:16.601 ios-sim4189806266868947871[31818:4531950] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[SimDeviceSet defaultSet]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x104d49118'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd536048b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffe9ac2cad objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd53e1bd4 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd52d2b55 ___forwarding___ + 1061
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffd52d26a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   ios-sim4189806266868947871          0x00000001016c3c21 -[iPhoneSimulator showDeviceTypes] + 75
    6   ios-sim4189806266868947871          0x00000001016c5dd1 -[iPhoneSimulator runWithArgc:argv:] + 3111
    7   ios-sim4189806266868947871          0x00000001016c5fb9 main + 101
    8   ios-sim4189806266868947871          0x00000001016c3150 start + 52
    9   ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (Exit value: 134)
9:09:16 AM: External task execution finished 'launchIPhoneSimulator'.
```

EDIT:

I found an ios-sim command in /.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.mobidevelop.robovm/robovm-dist/2.2.0/d8127badd4e98b6388f138216231c9b7a2e91fd/unpacked/robovm-2.2.0/bin/ios-sim

I think this is the ios-sim that's executed from gradle (I'm using the IntelliJ plugin). When I run the above with the showdevicetypes argument get the same error as in the IDE. Running the above with the --version command returns version 3.

So, is there some incompatibility between ios-sim and the version of XCode I have installed (8.1) or I'm I going down a rabbit hole?

Also, does this effect the problem: https://github.com/MobiDevelop/robovm/wiki/iOS-10-and-XCode-8-compatibility

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It says `+[SimDeviceSet defaultSet]: unrecognized selector`. It doesn't get any plainer than that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still confused about the exact issue (see EDIT in original post). Any help would be appreciated. - Thx

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question for the gluon people? As I understand it, you've paid good money for this thing.

Comment: With XCode 8.0 I had an error: `Failed to find class DTiPhoneSimulatorSystemRoot at runtime`, and now with 8.1 I have the same crash you are reporting. I'll create an issue on this.